# C++ trouble with extern - undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, extern

**main.cpp:**

```
bool lgstatus;
User currentUser;
//...
int main(){ //... }
```

**loginwindow.cpp:**

```
void LoginWindow::on_cmdCreate_clicked()
{
  extern bool lgstatus;
  extern User currentUser;
  //...
  currentUser.setMail(ui->txtAccountMail->text().toStdString());
  currentUser.setName(ui->txtAccountName->text().toStdString());
  currentUser.setPassword(ui->txtAccountPassword->text().toStdString());
  //...
  lgstatus = true;
}
```

My class `User` has 3 functions. Each of them takes a string as argument. I don't know whats wrong. The compiler doesn't complain if I change `lgstatus` but my `currenUser`.

Class :

```
class User
{
public:
    User();
    User(const std::string &name, const std::string &password);
    User(const std::string &name, const std::string &password, const std::string &mail);

    void setName(const std::string &name);
    void setMail(const std::string &mail);
    void setPassword(const std::string &password);

private:
    std::string user_name;
    std::string user_password;
    std::string user_mail;
};
```

The "set" functions simply pass their argument to the user_name etc. I don't think it would be necessary to show them as well.

Errors :

- undefined reference to 'User::setMail(std::string const&)'
- undefined reference to 'User::setName(std::string const&)'
- undefined reference to `User::setPassword(std::string const&)'

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling and linking `User.cpp` (or whichever file contains the implementation of the `User` class) along with the other source files too?

Comment: Do you have an include file to show the complete definition of `User` class?

Comment: You need to show the definition your User class.  With simple set methods, you probably want to define inline, and you probably only have method declarations.

Comment: How are you linking your program?

Comment: But not in the question above.  If you included a bit more code, we could confirm if there was a #include issue or a linker issue.

Comment: It's not about including "users.h" in both files. You need to compile all source code files at once (g++ main.cpp user.cpp login.cpp ...) because of linker.

Comment: Yeah that does QT creator for me.

Comment: Well I removed the extern and created an instance of that class only inside my loginwindow.cpp . It's still complaining "undefined reference".

Comment: Do you link in the file where the functions are defined? Because you definitely must "show" them to your compiler and linker.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely you are not doing the correct #include in your loginwindow.cpp.  As a result, the compiler never finds the correct functions.